# How to print Stack traces into log file?

Tags: java, logging, stack-trace

How to print Stack traces into log file, COM interface is calling our jar file, so need to know the stack trace for debugging.

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework for logging? Logback-classic? Log4j?
Do you want it in the system log or a separate log?

Comment: there's no information here whatsoever on how you print to log files currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use commons-logging and have code like:

```
private static final Log LOG_OBJ=LogFactory.getLog(YourClassName.class);
```

and then:

```
try {
    //Your implementation here
} catch(Exception e) {
     LOG_OBJ.error("Exception occurred", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is wrap system error stream and system output stream and redirect it to some file at startup of your application something like this:

```
 File logFile = new File("MyLog.log");

 PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(logFile));

 System.setOut(ps);
 System.setErr(ps);
```

This will redirect all your `System.out.print` and `printStackTraces` to log file `MyLog.log`

Or you can implement some logging mechanism using log4j or java logging.

Hope this helps.